# How to iterate for loop with values in different methods?

Tags: python

I made this program. What I want to do now, is to make a new *method* in the class `Star_cluster` that will **count** and **return** all planets in the star cluster that are in danger. In this case, a planet in danger is a planet with a star that has a short lifespan. A star has a short lifespan when it's total mass is more than 9.5 solar masses.

```
class Planet:
    def __init__ (self, a_str1, a_str2, a_float):
        self.name = a_str1
        self.type = a_str2
        self.orbital_period = a_float

class Star:
    def __init__ (self, a_float, a_planet_list):
        self.total_mass = a_float # in solar masses
        self.orbiting_planets = a_planet_list # list of Planet-objects

class Star_cluster:
    def __init__ (self):
        self.star_list = [] # list of Star-objects

    def add(self, Star):
        self.star_list.append(Star)
```

My problem is that I don't get how I should combine the values in the different methods to make one for loop.

For example, I tried to make something like this:

```
class Star_cluster:
    def planets_in_danger (self):
        for i in self.orbiting_planets:
            if i.total_mass > 9.5:
               k = self.orbiting_planets.count(i)
               return k
```

But I can't get this working. I want to understand how I should approach this problem, because I know what to do, but not entirely sure about how to do it the best way.

Especially whether to use `self` and the fact that there are multiple methods involved and just one for loop, confuses me. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: - Whether or not a `Planet` is endangered is decided at the `Star` level.
- So the number of endangered `Planet`s for the `Star` is also known at the `Star` level.
 - Therefore, the number of endangered planets in a `Star_cluster` can be decided by looping through the `Star`s.

So I think you should define one member function for the `Star` class, and one member function in the `Star_cluster` class.

Comment: What do you mean with member function? So, it's not possible to have just one function in Star_cluster to loop through values in other methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop over all the stars in the given cluster. If a star's total mass exceeds 9.5, count the amount of planets that belong to that star to the amount of endangered planets.

```
def planets_in_danger(self):
    in_danger = 0

    for star in self.star_list: 
        if star.total_mass > 9.5:
            in_danger += len(star.orbiting_planets)

    return in_danger
```

Or shorter:

```
    def planets_in_danger(self):
        return sum(len(star.orbiting_planets) for star in self.star_list if star.total_mass > 9.5)
```

edit: returning the count of endangered planets and the planets:

```
    def planets_in_danger(self):
        in_danger = []

        for star in self.star_list:
            if star.total_mass > 9.5:
                in_danger.extend(star.orbiting_planets)

        return (len(in_danger), in_danger)
```

Comment: Thank you. I like the straight forward method, as it doesn't confuses me that much. Thank you, @timgeb!

Comment: But @timgeb, what I do get, is this though: AttributeError: Star_cluster instance has no attribute 'orbiting_planets

Comment: @Siyah fixed, you need a collection of stars for each `Star_cluster`.

Comment: So, do I need just that piece of code, or do I need to add something like self.stars somewhere in my code? Didn't get that one

Comment: @Siyah As I wrote, you need to add a list `self.stars` to `Star_cluster` - how else would you know what stars belong to a cluster?

Comment: I got that, but that's something I thought I did with: self.star_list.append(Star). Isn't that correct, then?

Comment: @Siyah oh, my bad, I just read the lower definition of the class `Star_cluster` which does not have that list.

Comment: Okay, so would that change your code, then? And if I am correct, you are only counting the amount... right? You are not returning the planets... or am I wrong? Because I need to count AND to return all planets

Comment: @Siyah returning the planets in danger is a bit of a different question, but I'll write you a method that does just that.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that would be possible in the same for loop, but guess not then.

Comment: I didn't test the code yet, but I think that should be it. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Siyah note that returning `(len(in_danger), in_danger)` is a bit clumsy, I personally would just return the `in_danger` list and call `len` on that whenever you need the amount of planets.

Comment: thanks for the advice. When I run the code with the following, I get printed `0` and and empty list `[ ]`. Why is that?

`d = Star(12.0, ["Red", "Med", "Ced"])        
c = Star_cluster()
print c.planets_in_danger()`

Comment: @Siyah you did not add your Star to the Starcluster?

Comment: What do you mean? It confused me right now. Should I do c.add() ?

Comment: @Siyah this is basic. You have a Starcluster `c` without any stars. So of course you get `(0, [])` as the return value for `planets_in_danger`. You have a method on a Starcluster to add a star. So just do that.

Comment: Yes, but when I do this `c.add("Name of Star")` it gives me: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'total_mass'`. How do I use the parameter Star, then?

Comment: @Siyah `c.add(d)` of course. You want to add stars, not names of stars.

Answer (score 0):

## Call the function planets_in_danger in Star_Cluster

```
class Planet:
    def __init__ (self, a_str1, a_str2, a_float):
        self.name = a_str1
        self.type = a_str2
        self.orbital_period = a_float

class Star:
    def __init__ (self, a_float, a_planet_list):
        self.total_mass = a_float # in solar masses
        self.orbiting_planets = a_planet_list # list of Planet-objects

class Star_cluster:
    def __init__ (self):
        self.star_list = [] # list of Star-objects

    def add(self, Star):
        self.star_list.append(Star)
    def planets_in_danger(self, stars_list):
        result = []
        solar_mass = 1.989 * (10**30)
        for i in stars_list:
            if i.total_mass > 9.5 * solar_mass:
                result.append(i)
        return result
```

Comment: hope this helps